# Electron-forge Webpack "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" when compiled

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

I am writing an electron app which was built using electron-forge with Webpack and react.

This application works fine in the dev environement when I run it.

However once compiled using the squirrel.windows it it has the following error in the console.

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at compat:2
at index.js:2

This error can be bi-passed by setting nodeintegration to true as everyone and his dog suggests but this is not the secure way to do this. I am using a preload script and ipc/context bridge for front end to back end communication and I plan to continue to use this. I will sooner re-write the application to exclude Webpack which I believe to be the actual source of this issue.

Has anyone come across this issue? I've not found a single related topic anywhere and there is so very little information in the error message to even begin troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the cause of the issue was but doing an npm update seems to have resolved it.

I can only assume there were version conflicts when compiling that didn't show in the dev environment.

I hope this might help anyone else that finds this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).